# What is a "bass xylophone"?

Tags: instruments, orchestra, percussion, instrumentation, xylophone

In the instrumentation of the opera Turandot there is something called **bass xylophone**, but I couldn't find many things about it. What is it? And, since it doesn't seem to be a common instrument, how do orchestras substitute it if they doesn't have one? With a marimba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Italian Wikipedia (translation by Google)

> The instrument has a [range] that goes from G2 to G4, and [although] the notation for the instrument is [in] bass clef, ... the instrument plays [an octave higher], it is therefore a transposing instrument.

> The structure is more similar to that of a marimba than a xylophone, and its sound, quite dark, does not stand out much in orchestral ensembles.

> Since it is not very common, ... and **due to its large size, it is often ... replace[d] ... with the marimba**. [emphasis mine]

(Wikipedia: [Xilofono Basso](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xilofono#Xilofono_basso))

The Wikipedia entry is a paraphrase from *Le percussioni* by Guido Facchin ([pp. 357–358](https://books.google.com/books?id=DniXmlvb-6YC&pg=PA357&lpg=PA357))

However, this is contradicted by John Beck's *Encyclopedia of Percussion*, which says that

> **Bass xylophone** [is a] very low-pitched xylophone with a range of c to a' [C3 to A4]. It sounds as written and is played with large hard felt sticks. ([SOURCE](https://books.google.com/books?id=Aws3AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT173&lpg=PT173&dq=xilofono%20basso&source=bl&ots=52cyLSrVQA&sig=ACfU3U37ZYWUsJyEALbbwQYYV34VWi7D-w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9oOixv6T5AhUNGzQIHWwQCfgQ6AF6BAhFEAM#v=snippet&q=%22bass%20xylophone%22&f=false))

[English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylophone#Use_in_elementary_education) agrees with Beck about the instrument's range, but indicates that it

> sound[s] one octave lower than written.